# How to solve error in VS Code - exited with code=127

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Baffled by this. I've been using VSCode for a few weeks and have python installed.

```
def print menu():
    print ("Let's play a game of Wordle!")
    print ("Please type in a 5-letter word") 
        print_menu()
print_menu()
```

So far so simple, but when I run it I get this

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/worldle.py" /bin/sh: python: command not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.006 seconds
```

What does this mean? I'm guessing it failed but why? This appears to be trivial.

Tried:

```
def print menu():
        print ("Let's play a game of Wordle!")
        print ("Please type in a 5-letter word") 
print_menu()
```

Although I get an error on running script I can get an interpreter from python3.

Comment: I think you're missing an underscore in your function name

Comment: The problem is that `python` is not recognized as an installed program on your computer.  How did you install it?  Also, if you've been using VS Code for a few weeks, why is the problem just happening now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your function name is incorrect, you should keep the definition and call with the same name.

Then you can tell from your output that you are using ***Code Runner*** to run the code. You should install the official extension [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) to run the code. You also need to have a [python interpreter](https://www.python.org/downloads/) installed on your machine before installing the extension.

[image]

It would be helpful to follow this [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Error 127 in **Bourne shell** refers to a command not existing, you do not have python installed most likely, or it's not in PATH.

Also you have a space in `print_menu`'s definition.

Re-install python, fix the error and try again.

You can reinstall by downloading the installer from Python's website for windows/in general, on linux (ubuntu/debian) you can run

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python
```

Remember to also make sure that Python is added to PATH, after installing and rebooting, run:

```bash
$ python --version
```

If it shows the version it should work, otherwise it was not installed or [not added to PATH](https://realpython.com/add-python-to-path/)

Note, the first code shown is not possible to be ran because it has incorrect indentation, and were it fixed it'd have infinite recursion, the correct form of script you most likely desire is the last one shown with the underscore correctly placed.

Comment: I'd fixed the space screw-up. How do I reinstall Python.